# Why do i keep getting a Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, object-reference

In my app i have created 6 different pages with a final sub total on each page. Now i want to bring all those totals to the end page 'Total Page'. I use this code :

```
`App1.Signage.AnotherPagePayLoad passedSignParameter = e.Parameter as App1.Signage.AnotherPagePayLoad;
 double signEC = passedSignParameter.signEC;
 double signCost = passedSignParameter.signCost;
 txtSignageEC.Text = signEC.ToString("F2");
 txtSignageCost.Text = signCost.ToString("c");`
```

When i want to call signEC/signCost from the Signage page it gives me the error:
System.NullReferenceException occured but was not handled in user code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have been stuck on this for quite some time does anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: The most likely reason is that `e.Parameter` is not a `App1.Signage.AnotherPagePayLoad`. You need to debug and find out what it actually is.